Enable Offline Functionality for Ionic Web App
I'm not a developer, but I do work on some small coding projects for my wife's company.  I've built a vehicle inspection SPA app in vanilla JS Ionic.  A key requirement is that the app continue to work offline, and sync / submit collected data when a connection is restored.  Her company has a dedicated PHP / MySQL developer who handles all the back-end functionality.
My app is largely working, but the offline portion isn't.  I created a service worker which was mostly working, but Ionic files weren't getting properly cached if I linked to the files using the CDN links in my index.html file.  I was able to get the app working and caching properly by copying all the files in my node_modules Ionic directory locally, but only by placing them in my public directory and not having them processed by Vite.  I read that this likely wasn't the best approach for app performance, and did notice a slight degradation.  But at least it was working as expected, and I may revert back to that...
I've been going down a rabbit hole the last two days trying to import the Ionic components I'm actually using in my project into a JS module.  That is partially working, but none of my components are having the hydration class applied.  I basically have an app that is just a white screen, but if I inspect the HTML in dev tools all is working as expected, just not hydrating.
I'm wondering if it is possible to get this working by importing components, or if there is some way to cache local versions of the files served by the Ionic CDN as users interact with my app?  Here's a simplified / stripped down version of how I'm trying to import the components:
import { IonApp } from '../../node_modules/@ionic/core/components/ion-app.js';
import { IonContent } from '../../node_modules/@ionic/core/components/ion-content.js';

customElements.define('ion-app', IonApp);
customElements.define('ion-content', IonContent);

initialize();


Ionic components does not support hydration as of yet.

On another note, im confused to your question. Hydration has nothing to do with offline mode. you're mixing 2 different things. If you need to do offline mode, read here: https://ionic.io/blog/best-practices-for-building-offline-apps

Sorry; I might not be using the correct terminology. As I said, I'm not a developer, and the JS landscape has changed a lot since I was last using it for UX prototyping about ten years ago.  My primary issue as far as I understand it is that I'm not including all the Ionic files I need for my app to properly render - all works fine when I point to the CDN, but not when serving a subset of the files locally.

Can you post the errors that show in the console? Maybe that can help us give you a better answer.
